# Symfony - Generate URL for named route but does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, controller, routes, frameworks

I am novice at Symfony. Current version : 2.8.16
My problem : I don't manage redirection.

**app/config/routing.yml** :

```
gb_platform:
resource: "@GBPlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /platform
```

**src/GB/PlatformBundle/Ressources/config/routing.yml** :

```
gb_platform_home:
path :   /{page}
defaults: 
    _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Advert:index
    page: 1
requirements:
    page: \d*

gb_platform_view:
path :   /advert/{id}
defaults: { _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Advert:view }
requirements:
    id: \d+
```

**src/GB/PlatformBundle/Controller/AdvertController.php** :

```
namespace GB\PlatformBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AdvertController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $url = $this->get('router')->generate(
            'gb_platform_view',
            array( 'id' => 5)
            );
        return new Response("L'url de l'annonce d'id 5 est : ". $url);
    }

    public function viewAction($id)
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('gb_platform_home');
        //return new Response("lol");
    }
}
```

The error is the following :

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "gb_platform_home" as such route does not exist.

I can access manually to both route ("app_dev.php/platform/" can be reached).
But the URL generation is only working for **gb_platform_view**.

I supposed the source of the problem could be in app/config/routing.yml file specifying no itteration ... but if I do so it doesn't solve anything and seems to create more problems.

I find the debugging route command line :

> php app/console debug:router

Here is the result.

[image: Screenshot shell debug router]

gb_platform_home is clearing identify as a know route so I don't understand.
Also, you may notice there's a *shifted unique print* for this route in the shell. Why ? Key for solving ?

Could a 4 spaces encoding be the problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that you need to specify `page` value with your route usage. Something like `return $this->redirectToRoute('gb_platform_home', array('page'=>0));`

Comment: Can you try that dump($this->get('router')->getRouteCollection()); and check gb_platform_home route?

Comment: Piyush Singh : Problem unresolved as I expected because there is already default value for {page}.

Comment: You can try for debugging using `/platform/index/{page}` instead. Sometimes the routing sees it as ambiguous when the variable is not explicitly defined in the route.

Comment: I know it's a silly  question: but why are characters from the `gb_platform_home` line slightly to the left, compared to the rest? looks unusual. It came like this directly, or was this edited in any way?

Comment: It came like this directly. I had the same observation but I didn't notice it in the resume. I find it strange too ...
Maybe a 4 spaces encoding problem ? I'd be surprised because I took care of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution below should work as you expect.

`Requirement` and `Default value` will not work as you expect when generating route but rather when parsing the user entered url

your controler will need to be define like this:

```php
// you must set the default value like that `$page = 1`
function indexAction(Request $request, $page = 1)
```

```
gb_platform_home:
  path :   /{page}
  defaults: 
    _controller: GBPlatformBundle:Advert:index
    page: 1
  requirements:
    page: \d*
gb_platform_home_: <------ use it to generate your empty route
  path :   /
  defaults: { _controller: GBPlatformBundle:Advert:index }
```

Cause of things like that i prefer using route as annotation

- First rules is the one that will trigger when we receive the url with a {page} , you can name the route if you need
- Second rule same as first but we accept trailing slash
- Third rule to generate your empty route

```php
/**
 *  @Route("/platform/{page}", requirements={"page": "\d*"} ,defaults={"page":1})
 *  @Route("/platform/{page}/", requirements={"page": "\d*"}, defaults={"page":1}) 
 *  @Route("/platform", name="gb_platform_home")
 */
function indexAction(Request $request, $page = 1)
{
}
```